# How to validate JSON Schema in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, json, jsonschema

I have JSON returned from a server, and I would like to validate it against a JSON Schema (probably draft V3, can change though).

I thought that perhaps `NSDictionary` would have the functionality, but it doesn't seem to, here is my attempt:

`[self.dictionary ]`

(where `dictionary` is an NSDictionary)

There weren't any methods for validating the `NSDictionary` against a JSON schema that I could find. How do I do this?

Please note that you can write C and C++ in objective-c, hence these tags being present in the question.

Comment: I know of no in built way to do this, perhaps there is a third party solution but my guess would be you will have to write it yourself

Comment: You might have tried edit your closed question to get it reopened.

Comment: `JSON returned from a server, and I would like to validate it against a JSON Schema` note, not all JSON objects are dictionaries.

Comment: thanks ilya, a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After not finding a satisfactory answer to this question - I went away and developed my own schema validator in native Objective-c here: https://github.com/samskiter/KiteJSONValidator

I've just got it passing all the tests in the JSON-Schema test suite so I've released v0.1.

It's released under the MIT license so I hope it's useful to someone...

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C is a superset of C. JSON Schema site lists a C library **[wjelement](http://github.com/netmail-open/wjelement)**, you can adapt it.

The example function call is

```
WJESchemaValidate(schema, json, schema_error, schema_load, NULL, format)
```

You'll need to supply a C string, rather than `NSString`, naturally.

Note: after I wrote the answer, I realised you were fine with pure C from the start :)

Comment: yes, people kept removing my C tag and I'm not allowed to imply you suggest a C library (or my question will be removed.

Comment: Looks good, although not the neatest, as I'll have to munge my NSDictionary back to a string then to a C-string, but it does looks like a very mature library, so it should hopefully be worth it. Thanks

Comment: @Sam, it's better to use just `c` tag, then.

Comment: didn't want to open 3 questions ;)

Comment: Update: seems to be working! thanks. I think I may start work on a pure obj-c version at some point...

Comment: just finished and released v0.1 - it currently passes the JSON schema test suite. hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is looking for an MIT licensed JSON schema validator, "JsonSchemaValidator" does a nice job and is available here: https://bitbucket.org/nut_code_monkey/jsonschemavalidator

Comment: this is good, but doesn't look like it can parse a schema file, as defined by the JSON-Schema spec. It's a nice way of approaching the problem though, as it has typed and validated description language.